# why doesn't this code for passing data between controllers work?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, delegates

I'm trying to understand delegates so I created this simple app to test it out, I just want to pass a string from the secondViewController to the MainViewController... I tried to follow all the steps but it seems there's something missing and I don't have a clue about what it might possibly be... here's my code..

main view controller

```
class mainController: UIViewController, sendDataDelegate {

    let label: UILabel = {
        let lab = UILabel()
        lab.text = "No data"
        lab.textAlignment = .center
        lab.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return lab
    }()

    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    let secondVC = SecondViewController()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green


        //  assign delegate to self, not working...
        secondVC.delegate = self


        tapRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToSecondVC))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
        view.addSubview(label)

        // label constraints..
        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0":label]))
        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-200-[v0]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0":label]))
    }

    @objc func goToSecondVC(){
           show(SecondViewController(), sender: nil)
    }

    func passData(str: String) {
        print(str)
        label.text = str

    }

}
```

and the second view controller plus protocol to send the data...

```
import UIKit


//protocol to pass the data..

protocol sendDataDelegate {
    func passData(str: String)
}



class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    let tapRecog = UITapGestureRecognizer()

    let dataStr = "data passed"


    var delegate: sendDataDelegate?



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        tapRecog.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goBack))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecog)

    }

    @objc func goBack(){

//        trying to pass data here..
        delegate?.passData(str: dataStr)

//        dismiss view...
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

I'd like to point out I'm trying to learn everything by code, so no storyboards being used here.. how can I do this just by code?

thank you all in advance for the answers! have a great day)

Comment: When you are trying to show SecondVC set the delegate of your protocol.

Comment: Just a note: delegate in SecondViewController should be weak – `weak var delegate: sendDataDelegate?`, otherwise you will get retain cycle

Comment: Make sure to accept the answer that helped you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your function `goToSecondVC` you are creating a brand new view controller and ignoring the property that you created.

Change it to use `secondVC` instead of `SecondViewController()`.

Answer (score 2):

This correction will solve your problem:

```
@objc func goToSecondVC(){
    show(secondVC, sender: nil)
}
```

Protocols are better to be named with a capital letter:

```
 protocol SendDataDelegate: AnyObject {
     func passData(str: String)
 }
```

And don't forget about weak delegate:

```
weak var delegate: SendDataDelegate?
```

Comment: thank you so much for the hints, I'll remember that next time.

Answer (score -1):

change `goToSecondVC()` method as below:

```
 @objc func goToSecondVC(){
        let vc = SecondViewController()
        vc.delegate = self
        show(vc, sender: nil)
 }
```